# Pdfmake Javascript Array Issue

Tags: javascript, arrays, pdf, html-table, row

I am trying to create pdf with JavaScript using pdfmake. My question is I have array but I cannot loop array.

PDF

```js
function printPDF() {

  var activities = [
    ['Work', 9],
    ['Eat', 1],
    ['Commute', 2],
    ['Play Game', 1],
    ['Sleep', 7]
  ];



  var dd = {
    content: [{
        text: 'Teslim Formu',
        style: 'header'
      },
      {
        style: 'tableExample',
        table: {
          body: [
            [{
              text: 'Toplam Adet',
              style: 'subheader'
            }, {
              text: 'Etiket Değeri',
              style: 'subheader'
            }, {
              text: 'Toplam Ağırlık',
              style: 'subheader'
            }, {
              text: 'Sigorta Değeri',
              style: 'subheader'
            }, {
              text: 'Mağaza Adı',
              style: 'subheader'
            }, {
              text: 'Mağaza Yetkilisi',
              style: 'subheader'
            }],
            ["a", "b", "c", "d", "f", "g", "f"]
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        text: 'Ürün Bilgisi',
        style: 'margin-header'
      },
      {
        style: 'tableExample',
        table: {
          body: [
            [{
              text: 'Adet',
              style: 'subheader'
            }, {
              text: 'Barkod No',
              style: 'subheader'
            }],

            activities.flatMap((item) => {
              return [item[0], item[1]]
            })


          ]
        }
      },
    ],
    styles: {
      header: {
        fontSize: 14,
        bold: true,
        margin: [0, 0, 0, 10]
      },
      'margin-header': {
        fontSize: 14,
        bold: true,
        margin: [0, 20, 0, 10]
      },
      subheader: {
        fontSize: 12,
        bold: true,

      },

      tableHeader: {
        bold: true,
        fontSize: 13,
        color: 'black'
      }
    },
    defaultStyle: {
      // alignment: 'justify'
    }
  }


  pdfMake.createPdf(dd).open();


}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.59/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.59/vfs_fonts.js"></script>


<button class="convertPdf" onclick="printPDF()">PDF</button>
```

This is my code.

[image]

I am trying to do something like this. But It doesn't allow me to insert more than 1 array. It allows if my activities array just ['Work',9]. But If I add array more than Work 9 it gives me error : "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_calcWidth')".

Answer (score 0):

Your body's first array has 6 elements, while the second one has 7 ('a', 'b' ...).

As seen in [pdfmake's playground](http://pdfmake.org/playground.html), the table body's arrays cannot have different sizes :

```
  table: {
          body: [
            ["A", "B", "C"],
            ["D", "E"], (error: pdfmake expected 3 elems here)
          ], 
        }
```

As a workaround, you can add an empty string to the smaller arrays, to equalize :

```
  table: {
          body: [
            ["A", "B", "C"],
            ["C", "D", ""],
          ], 
        }
```